# What is the number of ways of choosing a of one object, b of another object, c of a third... and so on.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I recently learnt that if you had $n$ of object 1, and $m$ of object 2, you can find the number of unique arrangements as $\binom{n+m}{n}$.

How would this apply to multiple sets of distinct objects?

For example, how many arrangements - of length $13$ in this case - of $3$ identical apples, $4$ identical bananas, and $6$ identical pears would there be?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are the apples all alike?  Or is one a gala, another a red delicious, and the third a macintosh apple?  When you talk about "how many combinations of..." what size combinations are you talking about?  Do you want order to matter in these "combinations"?  If so, the word combinations is poor here... better to call them "arrangements" instead.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for the bad phrasing, yes the apples are identical, as are the pears and bananas. I am asking for the number of unique arrangements of the 13 fruits.

Comment: It *sounds* like you are asking for the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $\binom{a+b+c+\dots}{a,b,c,\dots}$ which simplifies as $\frac{(a+b+c+\dots)!}{a!b!c!\cdots}$ and can be shown to be equal to $\binom{(a+b+c+\dots)}{a}\binom{b+c+\dots}{b}\binom{c+\dots}{c}\cdots$.  In other words... you choose where the apples go.  Then, from those spaces left available, choose from *those* where the bananas go.  Then from those spaces left available, chose from *those* where the pears would go, etc...

Comment: Note that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+m}{n}$ is equal to the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n+m}{n,m}$.  Note also that just like we have the binomial theorem for talking about the expansion of $(a+b)^n$, there is a corresponding multinomial theorem talking about the expansion of $(a+b+c+\dots)^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz So just to check that I have calculated this right, my question comes to 360,360 unique arrangements?

Comment: $\dfrac{13!}{3!\cdot 4!\cdot 6!} = 60060$, not $360360$ and not $360$.  You were off by a factor of six for some reason.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks so much for the great explanation! I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collating comments:

This is a quintessential example of the usage of [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).  Another extremely common quintessential example people are more often first exposed to is the number of "arrangements of MISSISSIPPI."

The punchline at the end of the day is that you can get this with the tools you should already have been exposed to of rule of product and binomial coefficients.  First choose which spaces the apples get placed in.  Then from those spaces still available and not occupied by apples, pick where the bananas go.  Then from those spaces still left, pick where the pears go and so on until all fruits have been placed.  You get as an answer $\binom{13}{3}\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{6}$.  This is sometimes notated instead as the multinomial coefficient $\binom{13}{3,4,6}$

You can show this simplifies to $\dfrac{13!}{3!4!6!}$, and indeed for the general problem too the answer will be $\dfrac{(a+b+c+\dots+k)!}{a!b!c!\cdots k!}$

Note that just like we have the binomial theorem talking about the expansion of $(x+y)^n$, we have a multinomial theorem as well talking about $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m)^n$.  The coefficient of $x_1^ax_2^bx_3^c\cdots x_m^k$ where $a+b+c+\dots+k=n$ in the expansion will be the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{a,b,c,\dots,k}$